# CSS: Background image in select not working in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, drop-down-menu, background-image

I'm having a problem of getting `select` background image to work in React wth CSS. First of all I have the following file structure:

```
/src
|- globals.scss
|- /images
   |- caret.png
|- /components
   |- /Login
      |- container.js
      |- style.scss
      |- ui.js
```

Basically, `container.js` renders `ui.js` which imports `./style.scss`. This file starts with `@import /src/globals.scss;`. This is all working fine, but here is my problem. I'm trying to change the icon for select boxes using a custom background image. This code is located in `globals.scss` since I want to change this in all my select boxes to the same image. This CSS has the following:

```
select {
  outline: none;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;

  padding-right: 23px;
  background: url("caret.png") no-repeat right 5px center;
  background-size: 13px 8px;

  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  padding-left: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
```

This generates the following error:

```
./src/components/Login/caret.png
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\[...]\src\components\Login\caret.png'
```

So what I did is to add the missing file in the "Login" folder, which works fine. But for me this is not a good solution since I will have the `select` in many components and it feels totally stupid to have to copy the image into every component where I want the select. What I found was that I could try to change the `background` to `background: url("/src/images/caret.png") no-repeat right 5px center;`. When I did this, the error disappeared, but the image also disappeared from the select box (yes, the file is present in the "images" folder, I've checked).

How can I fix this?

I'm using webpack with sass-loader but I did not do the setup for this project, and I have no idea how the webpack config actually works if something is wrong there.

On a side-note: I tried to change the url to be the base64 for the image, which actually worked, but I'd like to find a solution that does not need to change every image to base64if I need to change this again in a similar way or somewhere else. Also I'm not sure if base46 works in every browser and I want to have cross browser support as far as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the `url` issues with `sass-loader`: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#problems-with-url

Typically you [resolve-url](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader) in your webpack config.

Comment: I tried this using the following:

{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'style-loader'
    },
    {
      loader: 'css-loader'
    },
    {
      loader: 'resolve-url-loader'
    },
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader?source-map',
      options: {
        outputStyle: 'expanded'
      }
    }
  ]
}

But that didn't work, still have the same error in console. Any suggestions? I added the package using npm.